# Missing game textures on XP VM (Parallels 6)

Tags: macos, virtualization, risen

I have an 1-year old 27'' iMac (8GB RAM) and am using [Parallels Desktop 6](http://www.parallels.com/) to virtualize a Windows XP installation. This is its *dxdiag* output:
 [image: DXDiag output]
While Games like *Civilization IV* work without any problem I get some strange artefacts when trying to play games like *Risen* or *Gothic IV*. While the main GUI (and the initial dialogs when starting the game) is colored correctly (see the text at the center and the health bar at the lower part) the main game is black and white. The performance is great, just all of the textures are missing: 
[image: Screenshot]
As nobody at the Parallels forum could help me I am trying to find someone here who has an idea what the problem might be.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the textures are indeed missing and not being rendered incorrectly, maybe you can append that folder path to an environment variable.  PATH comes to mind...

Comment: @Robb this neither occurs on only one game nor on one version (tried Steam, full game and demo one) so I don't think it does not *find* the textures on all those games. What does the *Path* environment variable has to do with this? As I know its (only) purpose is providing paths for executables, isn't it?

Comment: PATH also contains paths for shared libraries (unix) and dlls (windows).  I compile code with a lot of additions to my PATH env var.  My logic is this: Textures are (sometimes) loaded via a plugin which is called upon when requested by the game.  If it can't find the plugin OR the plugin can't find the textures it could be a pathing issue.  A lot of apps use the environment variable PATH to do its searching.  That being said, typically unix keeps PATH to binaries and uses LD_LIBRARY_PATH as its dynamic loading path var.

Comment: It was merely a suggestion, if you don't think that will solve the issue don't concern yourself with it.

Comment: @Robb I tried to add all related paths to the variable, but unfortunately it doesn't help at all, thanks anyway! While trying to search for related issues I discovered that users of [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxgames/) has similar issues while it's a complete different type of execution (virtualization over emulation).

Comment: If this is an issue with Parallels, MAYBE http://apple.stackexchange.com/ might help you. In my humble opinion, this question is relevant to both "gaming" and "apple" stackexchange sites.

Comment: @muffel: AFAIK, all modern PC "emulation" software actually uses virtualization. If they don't, they can't run fast enough. Crossover, on the other hand, works the same ways as Wine: it implements the "Windows API" on top of your current system. There is no emulation or virtualization happening.